# IOS Safari: unwanted scroll when keyboard is opened and body scroll is disabled

Tags: html, ios, css

There is a known technique to disable page scroll when modal window is opened.

CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body.disable-scroll {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
</head>

<body class="disable-scroll">
    <div class="page-content">
        <input type="text">
        ... content ...
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But on IOS Safari scroll becomes enabled after virtual keyboard is opened. And it scrolls more than even `window.innerHeight + window.scrollX`. Some blank gap appears at bottom of the page.
[image]

Editor's url
https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-snow-skuo5?fontsize=14

Fullscreen url to check on IPhone
https://skuo5.codesandbox.io/
Just open on IPhone or in XCode with IOS 12+ try to scroll and then focus on Input and try to scroll again.

Comment: +1 I have spent over a week trying to find someone else with this problem. No matter what I tried, I couldn't get rid of that ugly white gap at the bottom. Two possible solutions are to set the page background to match the content background (so the gap blends with the page and is less noticeable). Another is to apply `touch-action: none` on the `<html>` and `<body>` elements when text boxes get focus and remove the style when text boxes lose focus (this needs Javascript).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just went through tedious searching and seems that's an issue with iPhone as you have pointed in following article : https://blog.opendigerati.com/the-eccentric-ways-of-ios-safari-with-the-keyboard-b5aa3f34228d

So there is no way you can do it with css for sure.

But that doesn't stops you from using JQuery and Javascript **>:)**

Here is an untidy work around for your scenario. Have tested with multiple text boxes too ***on iPhone only***:

```js
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div class="page-content">
<input type="text" 
onfocus="disableScrolling(this)" 
onfocusout="enableScrolling(this)">
  <p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p>
  <input type="text" 
  id="text2"
onfocus="disableScrolling(this)" 
onfocusout="enableScrolling(this)">
  <p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p><p>Page content</p>
</div>`;

var currentElem; 

function stopScroll() 
{
    if(currentElem)
    {
        var top = $("input:focus").offset().top;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: top
        }, 500, function(){});
    }
}

function disableScrolling(elem) 
{
    currentElem = elem;
    document.addEventListener("touchend", stopScroll);
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        stopScroll();
    },10);
}

function enableScrolling() 
{
    currentElem = undefined;
    document.removeEventListener("touchend", stopScroll);
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body.disable-scroll {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-content {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="disable-scroll">
  <div id="app"></div>
  <div>End of body</div>
</body>
```

To explain in short what I did.

> **Problem** : User can scroll away while focusing on `textbox`

Assuming that,

> **Solution** : Allow user to scroll where ever he want and once he is done bring him back smoothly to where you want him to be;
>   `input:focused` :p

*Note : I have used JQuery to make things simpler. If you want to use pure javascript, you can find the replacement for the specific codes.*

Comment: Thanks for your post, it's a good idea to just scroll back to the focused input! Just two things: it would be nice to add the relevant code in the answer itself, that way the solution won't disappear when your links go dead. Also, I'm not really sure why you'd advice people jQuery and not vanilla javascript. jQuery really isn't necessary anymore nowadays.

Comment: Lolzz I am an old school guy :ppp I have worked extensively in JQuery in my initial days and over the top I am lazy too >.< !! I prefer `$("#target");` over `document.getElementById("target");` (shorter code length) ;) JQuery jus makes coding simple :) Check out "CODE" in [this site](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) Yes vanilla js can do stuff but it complicates many times with huge code. Like getting `offset()` or `animate()` used in answer will increase the code length and makes code unmanageable over the time :) P.S : Edited the suggestion btw ;)

Comment: I get what you mean, but using jquery requires you to load in an entire library whereas plain JS does not. You can't just assume that everyone uses jQuery nowadays. Being old school is no excuse for writing answers that apply to only a section of the audience instead of a broader range (unless the question was specifically tagged `jquery`)

Comment: Chill Bro. I am not good at my communicating skills >.< !! When I said i was old school, I wasn't justifying my suggestion. I was just letting u know y I m inclined towards jq. I very well agree to your point and that's why I have already removed the "jquery suggestion" part from my answer :)

Answer (score 18):

Just some info for anyone arriving here.

**Safari thinks this is feature.** There is a bug report [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=141832) (let them know you don't like this "feature" =]).

When you open the keyboard, the browser's `window` is moved up and your content is hidden because the `window` is out of the screen. Other weird behaviors can happen too, like the one the OP showed.

[image: Scrolling out of the screen]

Check this blog post for more details and more examples of weird behaviors (I copied the image above from it): https://blog.opendigerati.com/the-eccentric-ways-of-ios-safari-with-the-keyboard-b5aa3f34228d

Comment: safari is a new IE, that's what people say

Comment: There are (at least) 2 Safari bugs here - the one you linked to is related to retracting browser chrome and 100vh, which is explained better here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/url-bar-resizing 

The second bug is related to on-screen keyboard handling, and the fact that Safari adds scroll height when the keyboard is visible, and this behavior can't be controlled (and there is no resize event or other event to detect it).

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!!!!! Just please add those codes to your script

```js
//reach out to that input field (When ever u r gonna click tofocus)
let inputField = document.getElementById("input_focused")

 /*
 * Method 1: Briefly change the opacity.
 * Element might "blink" on focus in some scenarios.
 */
inputField.addEventListener("focus", () => {
      methodOne.style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(() => methodOne.style.opacity = 1);
    });
```

```html
  <section id="modal">
    <input id="input_focused">
  </section>
```

Check out for further information
https://gist.github.com/kiding/72721a0553fa93198ae2bb6eefaa3299

Comment: I cannot believe it this little hack actually fixed it for me! Do you have any explanation as to why this would fix it?

Comment: What is methodOne here?

Comment: Please explain your code better. How does changing opacity help fix the issue and what is `methodOne` in the code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kiding/72721a0553fa93198ae2bb6eefaa3299 I finally found where i did get it

Answer (score 0):

can you try this css please..

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body.disable-scroll {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Didn't fix it for me. Safari still allows scrolling when keyboard is open. Tested on XS.

Comment: please read this [blog](https://blog.opendigerati.com/the-eccentric-ways-of-ios-safari-with-the-keyboard-b5aa3f34228d). i hope it will help you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in one of my projects...

When you open the keyboard use this on body

```
$(body).bind('touchmove', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

And then unbind it when you want to scroll again

```
$(body).unbind('touchmove');
```

If you combine it with height:100% or 100vh and overflow:hidden. It should work.

Comment: In this old article https://benfrain.com/preventing-body-scroll-for-modals-in-ios/ they suggest the same approach for modal windows. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me on iPhone iOS13. When the keyboard is down, there is no scrollbar, perfectly fine, but as soon the keyboard appears, there's no control over body height anymore.

Comment: @KurtLagerbier Did you ever find a fix for this on iOS 13?

Comment: @Clifton No unfortunately not. I spent many hours on this and didn't find a proper solution. On Android it works just fine, but iOS13 wants to have a scrollbar.

Comment: @KurtLagerbier having the same issue . For android its OK but not for iOS.and yes once keyboard appears there in no control over body height.

Comment: I wish there would be something like this for web, as there is in React Native: https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to listen to these viewport height changes in JS:

```js
window.visualViewport.addEventListener(
  'resize', 
  event => console.log(event.target)
);
```

This works on iPhone (tested on physical iPhone 11 with iOS 15.1)

MDN doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Visual_Viewport_API

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by running this script which detects when the keyboard is showing and it will add class "kb_active" to body and the new offset value as an attribute to the body "data-window-offset" so we can use these values in css and another javascript code

```
function watch_mobile_keyboard_status(){
    // If mobile or tablet
    if(window.innerWidth < 950) {
        var kb_status = false;
        var initial_screen_size = window.innerHeight; // Checks initial height of the screen
        var interval_id = window.setInterval(toggle_kb_status, 1000);

        function toggle_kb_status(){
            if(initial_screen_size > window.innerHeight){
                if(!kb_status){
                    var diff = initial_screen_size - window.innerHeight;
                    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('kb_active');
                    document.querySelector('body').setAttribute('data-window-offset', diff);
                    kb_status = true;
                    document.dispatchEvent(new Event("change_keyboard_status"));
                }
            } else {
                if(kb_status){
                    document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('kb_active');
                    document.querySelector('body').removeAttribute('data-window-offset');
                    document.dispatchEvent(new Event("change_keyboard_status"));
                    kb_status = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here we can detect the event and move the element to the new postion

```
if(is_ios()){
    document.addEventListener("change_keyboard_status", function(){
        var element = ".nav_box";
        var offset = document.querySelector('body').getAttribute('data-window-offset');
        if(offset & offset > 50){
            if(document.querySelector(element)){
                document.querySelector(element).style.top = offset + "px";
            }
        } else {
            document.querySelector(element).style.top = "";
        }
    });
}


function is_ios() {
    return ['iPad Simulator', 'iPhone Simulator', 'iPod Simulator', 'iPad', 'iPhone', 'iPod'].includes(navigator.platform)
    || (navigator.userAgent.includes("Mac") && "ontouchend" in document)
}
```